# ggplot, I made a code but I want to make sure I get 2 tables based on facet now

Tags: ggplot2

So the following code indicates how many times a value is in my entire dataset

```
df %>% 
group_by(Branche) %>%
    summarise(Aantal=n()) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Branche, Aantal), y = Aantal))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Aantal), hjust = 2)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

in the dataset only 2 types of contracts are used, now I want to make a facet where the contracts become 2 different tables, that I can see which number belongs to contact A and contract B.

I thought I had to add "contract" in the group_by and then in the facet I only had to indicate contract, but this does not get the result that I get 2 different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` call.  Add it at the end here:

```
other code ... + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  facet_wrap(~ contract)
```

You may have issues correctly ordering the counts after faceting, but that would be another question.